# Why does my array not capture the object reference in it. but rather, keeps itself null

Tags: java, arrays, null

For the sake of simplicity, I have an abstract Java superclass that is called Insurance. It holds two variables and two abstract methods as follows

```
public abstract class Insurance {
    static String typeOfInsurance ;
    static double monthlyCost;

    public String getTypeOfInsurance() {
        return typeOfInsurance;
    }

    public double getMonthlyCost() {
        return monthlyCost;
    }

    public abstract double  setInsuranceCost();

    public abstract String  displayInfo();

}
```

I have another class that extends the abstract class (I am supposed to have 2 namely Auto and Home but for simplicity's sake ...) called Auto

```
public class Auto extends Insurance {

    @Override
    public double setInsuranceCost() {
        return getMonthlyCost();
    }

    @Override
    public String displayInfo() {
        return getTypeOfInsurance();
    }
}
```

In my driver class (main) i have tried to create an auto 'insurance' object that gets user input to fill in the type of Insurance and its monthly cost. This is retrieved from the user  by repeating the prompts to ascertain the type of insurance and its monthly cost. As oer the issue at hand, I then have to store each insurance object (created via the prompts) in an array of insurance objects with the appropriate values for the cost as gotten each time. I then have to call the insurance objects while running the setInsuranceCost() method on each one to display the cost of insurance for the Auto insurance again when printing each object out. I have struggled a lot trying to create the array, but all i get as an error is "Cannot invoke "exercise1.Insurance.displayInfo()" because "insurance" is null". An array list will give me the same issue im sure, so im asking for any help ! The main method runs as follows

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;


public class Main  {                            

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame;
        frame = new JFrame();

        Insurance auto = new Auto();
        Insurance home = new Home();

        Insurance[] insurances = new Insurance[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++) {

            Insurance.typeOfInsurance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please enter 
 type of Insurance - 'Auto' or 'Home' with a maximum of 5 of each");
            Insurance.monthlyCost = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please enter monthly fee"));

            if(Objects.equals(Insurance.typeOfInsurance,"Auto")){

                Insurance.monthlyCost = auto.setInsuranceCost();
                Insurance.typeOfInsurance = auto.displayInfo();
                insurances[i] = auto;

            } //else if (Objects.equals(Insurance.typeOfInsurance,"Home")){
                //Insurance.monthlyCost = Homes[i].setInsuranceCost();
                //Insurance.typeOfInsurance = Homes[i].displayInfo();
            //}
        }

        for (Insurance insurance : insurances){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Type of Insurance = " + insurance.displayInfo() + " " + "Monthly Fee = " + insurance.setInsuranceCost());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: First I would recommend not using static. Those are supposed to be objects instances. Second you should create the instances inside the for use temp variables to get the input them fill in the objects, Third the error you mention doesn't look like is in your code, assuming you changed it a bit for this question I see two things with the code as is, anything that is not *exactly* "Auto" (first capital A and uto lowercase) will end in a null pointer because your code is not handling it (you are using equals).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am verifying that my input is 'Auto' and no other variation of the word. i kept it static so that i could use the Insurance abstract class to reference and record the input and pass it to an auto object that is created after. The 'insurances[i] = auto' is what isnt capturing the object despite the fact that 'auto' is an insurance object.  Any more pointers ? I would welcome any changes you would suggest.

Comment: Edit - its the printing out something that is funny - it reocrds the last input for type of insurance and monthly cost that i provide and none of the others - that means the auto object referenced in insuraces is being created but each one of the instances auto is not being added to the insurances array ??

Comment: @Darosh I believe I provided a suitable answer to your posted question.

Comment: @hfontez, thank you very much and yes it did work ! I will keep what youve said below in mindin the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems with your code. The most egregious is the use of *static* variables as was mentioned in the comments section. A *static* member of a class is not unique to a single instance of the class. It is said to belong to the class itself. This is the reason why you don't use an object instance to invoke *static* methods. Instead, you use the class to do so. Likewise, *static* fields (variables) belong to the class and not to a unique instance. So, when you set a value in a *static* field, all instances of the class will contain the same value. In contrast, non-static fields are unique to a particular instance. So, when a non-static field changes value, it only changes in the instance where the value was set.

An example I like to use to illustrate when it is appropriate to use static variables is in a stadium scoreboard. Regardless how many scoreboards you may have in a stadium, when the score changes, you would want all scoreboards to display the same value. Therefore, this behavior will be optimal using *static* variables. To ensure this is modeled in software, the use of *static* variables will be appropriate.

In the OP's case, individual insurance quotes should be unique. Using *static* variables to hold *monthlyCost* and *typeOfInsurance* is causing all instances of Insurance (and by extension any of its subclasses) to have the same value for those fields. In essence, every instance created and added to the array will have the exact same values on both fields (which will be whatever was set last). To fix this issue, simply remove `static` keyword from your variable declarations.

The second problem was that the array was initialized to hold 5 entries, but the loop only created 3 entries. The second two indices in the array held null values and that is why the null pointer was thrown. To fix, you will need to reduce the limit in the display loop to 3 iterations, or allow setting 5 types of insurances to be set in the array.

I fixed other stuff in your code.

```
public abstract class Insurance {
    String typeOfInsurance;
    double monthlyCost;

    public String getTypeOfInsurance() {
        return typeOfInsurance;
    }

    public double getMonthlyCost() {
        return monthlyCost;
    }

    public abstract double setInsuranceCost();

    public abstract String displayInfo();
}
```

---

The main method in my solution looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame;
    frame = new JFrame();

    Insurance[] insurances = new Insurance[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Insurance insurance = null;

        String type = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,
                "Please enter type of Insurance - 'Auto' or 'Home' with a maximum of 5 of each");
        double cost = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Please enter monthly fee"));

        if (Objects.equals(type, "Auto")) {
            insurance = new Auto();
        } else if (Objects.equals(type, "Home")) {
            insurance = new Home();
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError("Insurance type not offered: " + type);
        }

        insurance.monthlyCost = cost;
        insurance.typeOfInsurance = type;
        insurances[i] = insurance;
    }

    for (Insurance insurance : insurances) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Type of Insurance = " + insurance.displayInfo() + " "
                + "Monthly Fee = " + insurance.setInsuranceCost());
    }
}
```

One last suggestion. Make your variables *private* and force the users of your `Home` and `Auto` classes to use the overridden setter methods to set these values.

Comment: Thank You and i will keep what youve advised in mind.

Comment: @Darosh If it fixed your issue, don't forget to click the check mark next to this answer. ;)